# two different .Click() functions working simultaneously and not individually - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When clicking the filter tabs, it functions fine but it scrolls the page right at the top. Could anybody please look at the code below what I'm doing wrong in the code.

Whereas Back 2 top function works fine.

I want these two functions to work separately because 1 is image filter and the other scrolls the page back to the top.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".button").click(function(){
                var name = $(this).attr("data-filter");
                if(name == "All"){
                    $(".filter").show("2000");
                }
                else{
                    $(".filter").not("."+name).hide("2000");
                    $(".filter").filter("."+name).show("2000");  
                }
            });
            $(".navigation a").click(function(){
                $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```
    <script>
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var height = $(window).scrollTop();
            if(height > 100){
                $("#Back2Top").fadeIn();
            }
            else{
                $("#Back2Top").fadeOut();
            }
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#Back2Top").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0}, "slow");
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I want both functions to function separately

Comment: Did you try preventing default in the `$(".navigation a").click`? Also please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates problem

Comment: You are talking about 2 functions but I see 6 of them.. 3 on outer scope. Which functions do you mean?

Comment: You're right when I clock on Back2Top button only the back2top trigger but when I click on image gallery filter it triggers both how do I separate it so 1 trigger at a time. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes it worked by adding

(function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();

Thanks, everyone for helping me out.

Answer (score -1):

This happens if you are using the same "button" class for both Bact2Top and filter.

You need to use different class name for filter.

Comment: <div class="button" id="test">Click Here</div>
<div class="button">Hello</div>
$(".button").click(function(){
    alert(1);
  });
  $("#test").click(function(){  
    alert(2);
  });
Here,if we click on 'Click Here' text, it will trigger both the alerts as it has two functions binded with it using the selectors '.button' and '#test'.  But if we click on 'Hello', only the alert 1 will be triggered as it has only event binded with it.

Comment: Result is the same

Comment: Can you plz make changes in my code and show me, thank you

Comment: I've tried changing the classes names but it still giving me the same result.

Comment: You're right when I clock on Back2Top button only the back2top trigger but when I click on image gallery filter it triggers both how do I separate it so 1 trigger at a time. Thank you